# Converting to base64 returns a very short string (too short)

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms

I'm submitting a form that contains sometimes single, sometimes multiple images. However when I submit an image, say `1.jpg`, the console output from my node server is `MS5qcGc=`. I assume that somehow the image isn't being sent through, only the text? How can I send through the entire image, and convert it to `base64`?

**Client**

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="imgs">Images</label><input accept="image/*" multiple name="imgs" type="file">
    </div>
</form>
```

**Server**

```
if (typeof req.body.imgs == "string") {
  console.log(new Buffer(req.body.imgs).toString('base64'));
} else {
  for ( i in req.body.imgs) {
    console.log(new Buffer(req.body.imgs[i]).toString('base64'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share other part of nodejs code, How are you handling request in middleware or before accessing req.body.imgs. it looks like you are getting only name of file in console.log.

Comment: @Abhishek I'm using express

Comment: Looks like Sam Axe answer will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `enctype` attribute with a value of `multipart/form-data` to your `form` element.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="imgs">Images</label><input accept="image/*" multiple name="imgs" type="file">
    </div>
</form>
```